# Getting an error as : 'changeMessage' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React. I wrote the following code in React JS and my code won't compile.

```
class Message extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super(); //Since we are extending another class, it is mandatory
        //this.state is an object
        this.state = {
            message: "Initial Message"
        }
    }
    changeMessage(){
        this.setState(
            {
                message: "Changed Message"
            }
        )

    }
    render()
    {
        return( 
            <div>
            <h1>
                {this.state.message}
            </h1>
            <button onClick = {() => changeMessage()}>Click to change message</button>
            </div>
            )
    }
}

export default Message
```

It was working fine before I added the onClick function for button.

Comment: `changeMessage` is a property of the prototype, not a standalone variable

Comment: try with `this.changeMessage()`

 i.e `onClick = {() => this.changeMessage()}` ..

Comment: Hi @satyam_m, adding 'this' worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to bind functions or use arrow functions

```
class Message extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(); //Since we are extending another class, it is mandatory
    //this.state is an object
    this.state = {
        message: "Initial Message"
    }
  }

  changeMessage=()=>{
    this.setState(
        {
            message: "Changed Message"
        }
    )
  }
  render() {
    return( 
      <div>
        <h1>
          {this.state.message}
        </h1>
        <button onClick = {() => this.changeMessage()}>Click to change message</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Message
```

Comment: Hi @Sachin Kammar,
Your suggestion for code change worked. I tried your suggestion without making changeMessage an arrow function and it seems to work with that too!
I think adding this keyword works.
Thank you!